# Defining a Form class in Django shell fails

Tags: django, django-forms

The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time." error when trying to execute a simple form related code.

I am learning Django using official documentation, I typed in the code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    pub_date = forms.DateField()

ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)

formset = ArticleFormSet()
for form in formset:
print(form.as_table())
```

Comment: Could this be your issue : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23146

Answer (score 0):

I found the following at https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1382023, replaced the code in django.core.wsgi.py file and I no longer get the error. The code can be found at https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi

> "Replacing our import + wsgi app creation function in django.wsgi [1] >appears to resolve the problem:
>
> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
> application = get_wsgi_application()
>
> Looking at the Django source all the way back to 1.4 [2], it looks like >we should be able to use this safely without breaking backwards->compatibility. Woohoo!